# Stripe 3D Secure Payment

Tags: php, flutter, stripe-payments, lumen

I am struggling to make 3D Secure Payments with Flutter and Stripe.

After I create a Customer I want to retrieve its payment options.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($user->stripe_id);
```

After that I create Payment Intent with that payment option:

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                'payment_method' => $customer->default_source,
                'amount' => 1234,
                'currency' => 'eur',
                'customer' => $user->stripe_id,
                'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
                'confirm' => true,
            ]);
```

Now in Stripe Dashboard it says that Customer must confirm transaction.

Then I do this:

```
$intent->confirm();
```

which produces following response:

```
{
  "id": "pi_1FxKveJNLhWWsjuJHdXC5tj7",
  "object": "payment_intent",
  "last_payment_error": "",
  "livemode": "",
  "next_action": {
    "type": "use_stripe_sdk",
    "use_stripe_sdk": {
      "type": "three_d_secure_redirect",
      "stripe_js": "https://hooks.stripe.com/redirect/authenticate/src_1FxKveJNjuJR4F2WkUA?client_secret=src_client_secret_GUJY8uSC9RbPhANkz7",
      "source": "src_1FxKveJNLhWWsjuJR4F2WkUA",
      "known_frame_issues": "false"
    }
  },
  "status": "requires_action",
```

What should I do next to make this payment successful? Navigate user to url given in response object? If I visit that url I can accept or decline payment, but it does not affect anything in Stripe Dashboard.

PS Client Side is mobile app (Flutter) and backend is Lumen PHP Framework.

I want to user to enter card once and then use that data for further purchase.

Comment: I might use something like https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment which should wrap Stripe's native mobile SDKs and allow you to confirm these payment intents from your mobile app rather than follow a redirect based flow.

Comment: As per the response, the _customer_ needs to confirm the payment. It’s nothing a developer can do. This is the whole intention of 3D Secure payments. You need to redirect the customer to the URL in the `next_action` object.